# Linking with start / end-group : why does my link fail unless some libs are left outside group

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors

I've been given the task of porting a working Visual studio build to gcc on Linux.

The solution has more than 60 projects. To link the final exe requires many static libs, some built by the solution, some external libs.

I've read about why the order matters to gcc (my basic understanding is that basically you need to order them so that the libs that require functionality are listed before the libs that provide them).

VS doesn't care about the order that the libs appear on the command line, so I did not inherit a meaningful order for the libs to appear.

With the number of libs involved finding a correct order seemed quite a large task, a currently correct order might be broken by later changes and besides there might be a circular reference in the libs. All that lead to me using start-group and end-group around the libs.

However I found that including all the libs in the group failed with an unresolved external but excluding some libs from the group and listing them after the end-group, would link.

That is

```
-start-group lSomelibA lSomelibB ...  lSomelibX lSomelibY lSomelibZ-end-group
```

failed with an unresolved symbol.

```
-start-group -lSomelibA -lSomelibB ... -lSomelibX end-group -lSomelibY -lSomelibZ
```

worked

```
 -start-group lSomelibA lSomelibB ...  lSomelibX lSomelibY lSomelibZ-end-group lSomelibY lSomelibZ
```

Which repeats those libs also worked.

I've read about start/end group, but couldn't see why including all the libs could fail.

Why would leaving a lib outside a group work when including it failed?

The unresolved symbol error references GLIBCXX an includes a version number, the exact message changes with reordering the libs. I'm guessing something might be defined more than once.

Comment: Your question is un-answerable without additional details, such as: which symbol(s) end up unresolved, and whether you include `-lstdc++` between `--start-group` and `--end-group` (don't to that!).

Comment: As it happens I don't include -lstdc++ in the group. But my question "Why would leaving a lib outside a group work when including it failed?" isn't specific to any libs or any symbols, it's about how the start-group end-group mechanism works.

Comment: Also if I had included it inside the group why would that fail? the documentation I have read on start/end group just says that it allows those libs to be searched multiple times. That in itself doesn't explain why inclusion in a group would cause a link failure.

Comment: What you described *shouldn't* happen. Since it *does* happen, *something* didn't work as expected. But without additional details, I can't even begin to *guess* where things went wrong. Maybe somebody else can. Good luck! Or you could provide additional details to make guessing easier.

Comment: OK, well that it shouldn't happen is interesting. That's how I interpreted start/end group - and really the only reason I mention my link in the question is that it clearly doesn't occur for all link lines. I clearly can't provide my entire solution, and if I knew to reduce it to a minimal example I'd probably also have identified the problem. So I was just hoping for what types of error could in theory possibly cause this problem - I'd then work out which applied to my case myself.